Detecting key press in unity
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using UnityEngine;

public class scr : MonoBehaviour
{
            public GameObject ow;
            private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = ow.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if (rb != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("RigidBody found");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("RigidBody not found");
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            Debug.Log("left shift key down");
            rb.mass = 0;
        }
    }
}

This is the code I have made for trying to detect a key press in unity.
Note that when I do press the key, neither does it log the message in the debug panel, neither does it change the mass of the rigidbody.
I have tried focusing the unity window, using getkeydown() and getkey() but nothing works. Everything else is fine. How can I fix this?

Did you attach this script to the GameObject that you want to modify? Does the "Rigidbody found" / "Rigidbody not found" messages get outputted?

Yes, the script is attached to the GameObject and it outputs "rigidbody found"

well as your script works for me, id say your object is not active.

What do you mean by not active and how can I make it so?

Try another KeyCode. like KeyCode.A

Different keycodes still gave the same result but I updated Unity and now it works

Found the solution. I updated my Unity version to the latest which seemed to fix the issue. Idk how it works but it does now :/

Try another KeyCode. like KeyCode.A.
then Try this options in Project Setting:

